# How to add hours to current date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've been tearing my head apart with this SQL statement, i'm trying to add 8 hours to the current day, because the server which is in another country and it updates at 8AM GMT. I want it to update at 12AM GMT hence adding 8 hours to current date, if someone could shed some light or a solution, i would be very thankful :) This is what I've got so far

```
("SELECT * FROM timetable  WHERE DATE (date) = CURDATE()");

("SELECT * FROM timetable  WHERE DATE (date) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 HOUR)");
```

That's what i came up with but it doesn't display anything :(

Comment: Or you could just think in another way, like subtracting 8 hours from the data, ``DATE_SUB(DATE(`date`), INTERVAL 8 HOURS) = CURDATE()``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE DATE (date) = date(now()+interval 8 hour)
```

Comment: Yes! Genius! I tested it with +23 hours and +22 and the date changes at +23 oh your a star mate cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql has a [timezone conversion command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value. Time zones are specified as described in Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”. This function returns NULL if the arguments are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE datetimefield >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
```

datetimefield should be of timestamp
thanks